# how to upload file using watir

Tags: ruby, rubygems, watir, webautomation

I'm new at automation test, but I want to make automation testing upload a photo using watir but the photo can't uploaded and not show any error, I'm using ruby v2.7.4p191 and watir v.6.19.1.

this is html:

```
<div class="file-attachments">
</div>
<div class="dropzonePreview" id="dropzonePreview">

</div>
<div class="dropzoneAdd dz-clickable" id="dropzoneAdd">
<div class="addText">
<div class="fa fa-cloud-upload"></div>
Drop file to attach, or 
<span style="color:#22B5E7; text-decoration: underline">
browse
</span>
</div>
<div class="addText-detail">
max size 10 MB/file
</div>
</div>
<div class="dropzoneMaxFileReached" id="dropzoneMaxFileReached" style="display:none">
Maximum upload file has been reached
</div>
```

this is ruby code

```
@browser.file_field.set "C:banana.jpg"
```

Comment: Can you check that you're setting the right file field? In the HTML provided, I don't see a file field (ie an `<input type="file">`). The Watir code provided is setting the first file field on the page. It could be possible that the one you want is not the first one. Try checking if there are multiple - eg `puts @browser.file_fields.count`.

Comment: This is the right one in ruby `C:\\banana.jpg`

Comment: @JustinKo yes this is the problem, i have checked inspect element from browser but can't find input element. but the html is provide uploading image. is there something i missed?

Comment: Can you get the output of `@browser.file_fields.count` and `@browser.file_fields.map(&:html)`?